# PHP class variable not assigned

Tags: php

I am having a strange issue with my php code. This is the php version I am using `PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.30 with Suhosin-Patch`.

The issue I am having is that I cannot assign an anything to a variable that is part of my class

```
namespace Stats\POTSPortStats;


use PDO;
use Stats\Port;
use Stats\POTSPortStats\IPHosts\IPHosts;

class PortStats extends Port
{

    public $vcPortOnHookStatus;
    public $vcPortImpedance;
    public $ipHosts;

    /**
     * @param $secretValue int
     * @param $pdo_conn PDO
     * @return PortStats[]
     */
    public static function getAll($secretValue, $pdo_conn){
        try {
            $query =
                "SELECT * FROM secretTable WHERE secretColumn = :secretValue";
            $pdo_stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
            $pdo_stmt->bindValue(":secretValue", $secretValue, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $pdo_stmt->execute();

            /** @var PortStats $result */ //This works right
            $result = $pdo_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, __CLASS__);

            //other is assigned an Array of IPHosts classes
            $other = IPHosts::getAll($secretValue, $pdo_conn);
            echo json_encode($other);
            //Checked for result, it is there.
            $result->ipHosts = $other;

            //Check just assigned value
            var_dump($result->ipHosts);
            //Value was NULL
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            //nothing here
            var_dump($e);
        }
        //The rest of the result is returned correctly
        return $result;
    }
```

Is there something wrong with my code that I am overlooking? Is there some kind of bug inside of this version of PHP that I did not find when I looked? Any help would be much appreciated. Please ask if you need more clarification.

Comment: Any errors showing? More importantly is error reporting enabled?

Comment: I don't see any errors.

Comment: Ensure that PHP is set to display all errors: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: I don't see any assignments to public properties of class

Comment: If you are trying to change a database value like that, it won't work. You need to use `UPDATE`. Also remember your variables are `non-static` yet your function is `static`.

Comment: @Script47 it isn't changing anything in the database, but I may have just seen what was wrong with it.

Comment: your ipHosts property is not public.

Comment: off topic, but please note that PHP 5.3 is quite out-of-date by now. Even 5.4 is out of support. You should seriously consider upgrading to 5.5 or 5.6 sooner rather than later, so that you don't get too far behind. (it can get very difficult to upgrade the longer you leave it, as you may be forced to jump more versions at a time, and deal with more breaking changes at once)

Comment: @Simba I know that however it isn't up to me, The company I work at still has 5.2.9 on some of it's servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
$result = $pdo_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, __CLASS__);
```

Are you sure that pdo_stmt->fetchAll(...) returns an object of type PortStats? I don't think it does. It returns an array. And even more so, I don't think you can implicitly cast to class PortStats.

Try:

```
$results=$pdo_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, __CLASS__);
foreach($results as $result){
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking I haven't had the chance to test it yet though

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but I am pretty confident that this is what the problem was, It is amazing how it is possible to miss these kind of things, and see it like a minute after you post it.

Comment: It should have been /** @var PortStats[] $result */ and then change some code in the `IPHosts` class

Comment: @DreamBlob OK everything works now, Spent 2 hours staring at that code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be an issue on the following line.

```
$other = IPHosts::getAll($nCircuitStatsID, $pdo_conn);
```

I can't see `$nCircuitStatsID` being defined anywhere else in your code.
Is it a global?

I would also expect `fetchAll()` to return an array of type `__CLASS__` rather than an instance of `__CLASS__`.

Comment: That is the same as $secretValue, forgot to change it.

Comment: In that case, I expect the problem is the same as @DreamBlob outlined.